# SubSonic 2.2 + SharedDbConnectionScope

Tags: c#, subsonic, shareddbconnectionscope

I have seen posts [(first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327871/subsonic2-2-shareddbconnectionscope-and-transactionscope-transaction-confusion), [second)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242988/subsonic-using-shareddbconnectionscope-together-with-transactionscope-seems-to-b) on StackOverflow that say that SubSonic 2.2's SharedDbConnectionScope doesn't work with TransactionScope.

Can we still rely on SharedDbConnectionScope in other contexts? I want to know if I should be concerned when using code such as the following (where ProviderName is not the default provider for item's type):

```
using (var scope = new SharedDbConnectionScope(DataService.Providers[ProviderName]))
{
    item.Save();
}
```

In my system, it looks like it works fine, but I think I may have had it try to save to the wrong database on rare occasions (may be unrelated).

Thanks!